# Reporting framework for the application

Tags: java, reporting

i have an application for which i want use some reporting framework to generate some reports. i have no idea about this. so i wanted to know some good reporting framework available.
        with easy to understand. 
        facility to generate pdf's
        and java friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=jasperreports). *"JasperReports is the world's most widely used open source reporting engine."*

Answer (score 1):

[iText](http://itextpdf.com/) is a great framework for creating PDFs

Answer (score 0):

[i-net Crystal-Clear](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear) is a great framework with a great support. *"i-net Crystal-Clear is the world's most widely used commercial reporting engine for Java."*